# Graph categorical variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, geom-bar

[Picture of how I want the graph to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VAlE.jpg)

I have a dataset with the following 3 variables:

1. Condition, categorical with 3 levels: control, eyes, camera
2. mean_destruction, continuous, values range between 0-10, n=120
3. mean_expectation, continuous, range between 0-10, n=120

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Condition = c(rep('Control', 40), rep('Eyes', 40), rep('Camera', 40)),
                 mean_destruction = sample(0:10, 120, replace = T),
                 mean_expectation = sample(0:10, 120, replace = T))
```

I am trying to graph this in ggplot 2 and failing.  Here is one of my many *ahem* efforts to reproduce the below image:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x= Condition, y=(mean.destruction), fill=(mean.expected)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Note the link above to a picture of what I am actually trying to achieve - and could have done hours ago if we still did everything by hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that uses dplyr and tidyr.

Here's how I'm interpreting your data:

```
set.seed(2112)

df1 <- data.frame(Condition = c(rep('Control', 40), rep('Eyes', 40), rep('Camera', 40)),
                 mean_destruction = sample(0:10, 120, replace = T),
                 mean_expectation = sample(0:10, 120, replace = T))
```

You'll need to transform your data into long so you can get different bars for `destruction` and `expectation`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
      gather(mean_destruction, mean_expectation, key = mean_type, value = value) %>% 
      group_by(Condition, mean_type) %>% 
      summarize(mean = mean(value))

> df1
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: Condition [?]

  Condition        mean_type  mean
     (fctr)            (chr) (dbl)
1    Camera mean_destruction  4.90
2    Camera mean_expectation  5.20
3   Control mean_destruction  4.85
4   Control mean_expectation  5.30
5      Eyes mean_destruction  4.40
6      Eyes mean_expectation  4.15
```

Then your ggplot2 call just needs a bit of tweaking:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x = Condition, y = mean, fill = mean_type)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge', colour="black")
```

[image]

Comment: That was fantastically quick - thank you.  R doesn't seem to be able to find the function 'gather' though, I have installed and called dplyr.  Any thoughts on what's up?

"Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "gather""

Comment: Got it - it's a "tidyr" function.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I think there might be an error in the code above - if I run it the data collapses to 1 observation of 1 variable after:

      group_by(Condition, mean_type) %>% 
      summarize(mean = mean(value))

This true both if I run the code above exactly as provided to try to replicate what you have done BLT and also if I try to adapt it to my dataframe.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the libraries in. I just ran this with a clean R session and it works, so it might be a version problem. I'm on R version 3.2.4, dplyr 0.4.3, ggplot2 2.1.0, and tidyr 0.4.1.

Comment: Thank you again.  This is working fine now. Note for others: it won't work if you are running dplyr and plyr at the same time.  Not sure why.  

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.